# Including file from class

Tags: php, include

I have the following file structure:

```
www
|-- MyLibrary
|    |-- Example.class.php 
|    +-- someDirectory
|         +-- somefile.php
|-- other_file.php
+-- another_file.php
```

I want to include a file from a class:

```
<?php
    class Example {
        public function test(){
            include "someDirectory/somefile.php";
        }
    }
?>
```

It will throw an error because it's including from an other file/directory than the class. Since I'm writing a library I don't known the directory where the files will be in and the path from the file creating the instance and 'somefile.php'.

**So my question is:** Is there a way to include 'somefile.php' from 'Example.class.php'?

Comment: You could use the php autloader system which greatly simplifies this kind of problems. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php You could also use a constant containing the absolute path to your app that you prepend to the include path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `__DIR__` constant in PHP

> The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to dirname(`__FILE__`). This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is the root directory.

(https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

So that will be:

```
<?php
    class Example {
        public function test(){
            include __DIR__."/../someDirectory/somefile.php";
        }
    }
?>
```

With this you use the relative path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current path that the file is in.

In the structure you're working, you can rewrite the Example class to this:

```
<?php
    class Example {
        public function test(){
            include __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "someDirectory/somefile.php";
        }
    }
?>
```

The `__DIR__` constant will give you the current folder.